# Tag for questions about definitions and approach

Tags: discussion, tags

I asked [this question about Coq](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/724/coq-implementing-a-type-thats-constrained-to-satisfy-a-predicate) recently.

I'm curious what the correct tag would be for this type of question. In the linked question, I'm asking about the possible ways of **taking a pre-existing type and creating a new type by constraining its instances to satisfy some property**.

When I wrote that question specifically, I was assuming there was a bread-and-butter Coq feature that would do this (hence the dependent type tag).

[Guy Coder](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/users/5/guy-coder), however, raises an interesting point.

**What tag should be used for questions about how approaches for defining things within proof assistants that make proving things convenient/tractable/elegant?**

Answer (score 2):

<s>How about [best-practices](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practices)?</s>

I believe the phrase "best practices" could cover features and strategies for writing code (e.g. designing data types and writing proofs) in a specific proof assistant that make proofs "convenient", "elegant", or "idiomatic".

After reading the post linked by V2Blast, I get that "best practices" is a frowned upon phrase, and therefore not the best tag here.

Not every aspect of all possible questions needs a tag. If you have your own code that works and want to ask for a better way to achieve the same thing, there's [proof-review](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-review) (and OP's linked question falls into this category). If you don't, it falls into a very general category of questions "How do I do X [in proof assistant Y]?" which probably doesn't need a tag of its own. (One might suggest [usage](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) which already exists, but I believe it is way too broad for a tag. This is a topic for another meta post though.)

Comment: Potentially relevant MSE (originally MSO) post: [Why is asking a question on "best practice" a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353/335251)